# How to operate on values in Google sheets custom functions?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Here's my attempt to calculate a filtered sum:

```
function computeBalance(account, from, to, amounts) {
  var balance = 0

  from.forEach(function (name, index) {
    if (name == account) balance - toCents(amounts[index].toString())
  })

  to.forEach(function (name, index) {
    if (name == account) balance + toCents(amounts[index].toString())
  })

  return balance
}


// Some money helpers

function toCents (dollarString) {
  return +dollarString.replace(/[\$\,\.]/g, '')
}

function toDollars(cents) {
  return (cents / 100)
}
```

So, the problem is the toString() function. It just coincidentally exists on the Google Sheets object that gets returned from the amounts array. I have no idea how to actually get the value itself, the dollar String that I can convert to cents, so I can do my math.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You could try either making your own "toString" method, or try to add quotes to the item. So it would be

```
(amount[index] + "")
```

Comment: That produces the same result as what I currently have.

Comment: damn, well since you have a procedure for making them ints can you put them in the array as strings? Or, just seeing this now, it could be because you are turning them to strings but then subtracting them from an int? Maybe it should read (balance +/- amount[i]).toString. Also where are you checking that it is becoming a string, it looks like you are just doing this to put a string through the cents method why not change that to take a double or int?

Comment: One of the challenges is that the debugging tools for this are pretty bad. All I can do is see what I return from the custom function, after Google Sheets cells operate on the value. I can't log to a console or anything. This is really annoying.

Comment: hmm that is awful, well I would try either changing you "toCents" method to take whatever is being passed, or make your own version of "toString" and call it something else.

Comment: I needed a plus equals, not just plus or minus in the adjusting balance. No more coding this late at night for me : (